# How to reverse paginate order from last page to the first page

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get "backwards pagination" working for a forum that I'm working on. Each thread has replies that is supposed to have the last three pages available during rendering.

I've tried many different ways to get it work using for and foreach loops. However, I either have 10 11 12, 10 11 12, for each record, or I have 10 10 10, 11 11 11, or 12 12 12 for each record.

This is the code I have so far.

```
                @php($j = array())

                @for($i = $thread->replies->count() - 2; $i < $thread->replies->count(); $i++)
                @php($j[] += $i)
                
                @endfor  

                @foreach($j as $number)
                    {{ $number }}
                @endforeach

                @foreach($thread->replies->paginate(1)->setPath($thread->path())->getUrlRange($thread->replies->count() - 2, $thread->replies->count()) as $pagination)
                    <a href="{{ $pagination }}">
                        
                    </a>   
                @endforeach
```

Now, this works as far as having the *numbers*, but once I put

```
            @foreach($j as $number)
                {{ $number }}
            @endforeach
```

inside the "getUrlRange" loop, I get duplicates.

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong? I've tried to get this to work but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: if you paginate from DB why not using laravel pagination ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure how to reverse the page order, this is specified to each thread

Comment: you can reverse the order of record itself by using `orderBy` option when calling from DB and let the default paginate as it is, is this solve your issue? or you stick to reverse pages order from the last page to page number 1?

Comment: I want to stick to reverse pages order from last page to page number 1

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your issue this way:

in your controller send paginate to the view something like:

```
$pagniation_name=model_name::all()->paginate(10);
```

in your view blade

```
// content displayed here

    @php
        $last_pages_links = array_reverse($pagniation_name->links()->elements[4]);
        foreach ($last_pages_links as $page_link) {
            $last_pages_no[]=explode('page=',$page_link)[1];
        }

        $first_pages_links = array_reverse($pagniation_name->links()->elements[0]);
        foreach ($first_pages_links as $page_link) {
            $first_pages_no[]=explode('page=',$page_link)[1];
        }
    @endphp

    // display paginate links:
    <a href="{{ $pagniation_name->previousPageUrl() }}">Prev</a>
    @foreach ($last_pages_links as $key=>$page_link)
        <a href="{{ $page_link }}">{{ ($last_pages_no[$key]) }}</a>
    @endforeach
    {{ $pagniation_name->links()->elements[3] }}
    @foreach ($first_pages_links as $key=>$page_link)
        <a href="{{ $page_link }}">{{ $first_pages_no[$key] }}</a>
    @endforeach
    <a href="{{ $pagniation_name->nextPageUrl() }}">Next</a>
```

hope that will help you, of course, you have to add your styles and test different scenarios, also something may be helpful to you to run :
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` and see the `resources\view\vendor\pagination` and you can apply any changes there to be your default pagination

Comment: Hi, I just tried to run your code but I did not have nay success in getting the pagination to display.

Comment: I tried my code before posting in a real project, so I'm confident it works. tell me what's the error message in order to help you overcome

Comment: It runs, there are no errors, but nothing is displayed. I removed some of the code but it looks like the $escalation variable is not set.

Comment: sorry I fix $escalation variable, it was my project example I tried my code on, please try again and tell me the results

Comment: review your styles , page source code and try to debug using `dd()`

Comment: give me the results of  `dd($pagniation_name->links())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218168/discussion-between-ibrahim-ezzat-and-user123).

Comment: Still can't figure out why I get the undefined offset 4 error. Can anyone please chime in?